# Why is Meteor 1.4 loading jQuery 1.11.2?

Tags: jquery, meteor

I have a big problem working with jQuery on Meteor 1.4 with React. When installing jQuery using "meteor add jquery", it installs jQuery 1.11.9. For some package dependencies, I need to have a newer version of jQuery. So, I removed jQuery 1.11.9 under Meteor, and added jQuery 2.1.4 using npm. Both appear to be correctly done.

When a page is loaded, the loaded jQuery file indicates that it's at version 1.11.2.

This is very puzzling. Does anyone have the same experience? Any solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read [this thread](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-1-3-require-conflicting-with-jquery-plugins/20298)

`mxab` answer:

> I'm also struggling with this issue. I'm trying to use fullcalendar
>   from npm but it also contains which has a require("jquery")
>
> This hack works for me so far:
>
> 1) adding my preferred jquery version via cdn into the html itself
>
> ```
> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
> ```
>
> 2) overriding the jquery package: packages/jquery/package.js:
>
> ```
> Package.describe({
>     version: '1.11.6'
> });
>
> Package.onUse(function (api) {
>
>     api.use('modules-runtime');
>
>     api.export('$', 'client');
>     api.export('jQuery', 'client');
>     api.addFiles('index.js', ['client']);
>
> });
> ```
>
> packages/jquery/index.js:
>
> ```
> //as we have it added as cdn in the head, jQuery is available
> jQuery = window.jQuery;
> $ = window.jQuery;
>
>
> meteorInstall({
>     node_modules: {
>         jquery: function (r, e, module) {
>             module.exports = jQuery;
>         }
>     }
> });
> ```